# why for all open interval in $\mathbb{R^1}$ it must contains both rationals and irrationals numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As the topic, why for all open interval in $\mathbb{R^1}$ it must contains both rationals and irrationals numbers, exist any prove?

Answer (score 1):

This must be proved in two stages.  First, given an open interval $(a,b)$, we must show that it contains some rational number $q$, then we must show that it contains some irrational number $r$.

@AsinglePANCAKE's answer already has [a link](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Between_Every_Two_Reals_Exists_a_Rational) to the first stage.  So consider this done.  That is, there is $q\in{\Bbb Q\cap(a,b)}$.  Now, if $b\in{\Bbb Q}$, then let $r=q+(b-q)/\sqrt 2$, which is both irrational and inside $(a,b)$.  Alternatively, if $b$ is irrational, then let $r=(q+b)/2$, which is irrational and inside $(a,b)$.

So we always have rational $q$ and irrational $r$ inside $(a,b)$.